# How prove $ \sum (a+b+c+d)\sum\frac{ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd}{a+b+c+d}\sum\frac{abc+abd+bcd+cda}{ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd}\leq \sum a\sum b\sum c\sum d$

Tags: inequality

let $a_{i}>0,b_{i}>0,c_{i}>0,d_{i}>0,i=1,2,\cdots,n $

show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_{i}+b_{i}+c_{i}+d_{i})\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_{i}b_{i}+b_{i}c_{i}+c_{i}d_{i}+d_{i}a_{i}+a_{i}c_{i}+b_{i}d_{i}}{a_{i}+b_{i}+c_{i}+d_{i}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_{i}b_{i}c_{i}+b_{i}c_{i}d_{i}+c_{i}d_{i}a_{i}+d_{i}a_{i}b_{i}}{b_{i}c_{i}+c_{i}a_{i}+a_{i}b_{i}+d_{i}a_{i}+d_{i}b_{i}+d_{i}c_{i}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{a_{i}b_{i}c_{i}d_{i}}{a_{i}b_{i}c_{i}+b_{i}c_{i}d_{i}+c_{i}d_{i}a_{i}+d_{i}a_{i}b_{i}}\le\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}$$

I think this true, because yesterday I have proved this

[$\sum a+b+c \sum \frac{ab+bc+ca}{a+b+c} \sum \frac{abc}{ab+bc+ca} \leq \sum a \sum b \sum c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/410112/sum-abc-sum-fracabbccaabc-sum-fracabcabbcca-leq-sum-a-s/410178#410178)

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Wow. Assuming I was drunk enough to try proving this monstrosity-I'd try induction.

Comment: Thank you,can you post your solution?

Comment: I'll try and get it done today,but rather busy.

Comment: I'm halfway through it and it's just an ugly computation. just ugly.Not difficult,but just grotesquely tedious.Wish I still had my MATHEMATICA right now,would make it a lot quicker since I could get it to do the spade work.

Comment: I'm exhausted. If I have time before the deadline,I'll try and finish it.I got stuck on how to rearrange it correctly for the inductive step. I'm VERY sure this how to do it,but too tired to work it out now and can't drink coffee for health reasons. I hate being sick...........

Comment: I'm curious if $S_{k+1}/S_k$ is always a concave function of its arguments where $S_m$ is the $m$-th symmetric sum. This would give the desired result in no time. For $3$ variables it is, indeed, so, and for $4$ variables only $S_3/S_2$ is unclear.

Comment: In all honesty I don't even understand the question. Without parentheses, I don't know which sigmas are inside of which other sigmas, and what is being multiplied by what.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum a_i \sum bi \geq \sum ( a_i +b_i ) \sum \frac{a_i b_i}{a_i+b_i}( Milne)$$
$$\sum c_i \sum di \geq \sum ( c_i +d_i ) \sum \frac{c_i d_i}{c_i+d_i}( Milne) $$
$$ \sum a_i \sum bi \sum c_i \sum di \geq  \sum ( a_i +b_i ) \sum \frac{a_i b_i}{a_i+b_i} \sum ( c_i +d_i ) \sum \frac{c_i d_i}{c_i+d_i}$$
$$ = \sum ( a_i +b_i ) \sum ( c_i +d_i )\sum \frac{a_i b_i}{a_i+b_i} \sum \frac{c_i d_i}{c_i+d_i}  $$ 
$$ (Milne ) \geq \sum ( a_i +b_i + c_i+d_i )\sum \frac{(a_i+ b_i)(c_i+d_i)}{a_i+b_i+c_i+d_i} \sum(\frac{a_i b_i}{a_i+b_i}+\frac{c_i d_i}{c_i+d_i})\sum \frac{\frac{a_i b_i }{a_i+b_i}\frac{c_i d_i}{c_i+d_i}}{\frac{a_i b_i }{a_i+b_i}+\frac{c_i d_i}{c_i+d_i}} $$ 
$$ \geq \sum ( a_i +b_i + c_i+d_i )\sum \frac{(a_i+ b_i)(c_i+d_i)}{a_i+b_i+c_i+d_i} \sum \frac{a_ib_i(c_i+d_i)+c_id_i(a_i+b_i)}{(a_i+b_i)(c_i+d_i)} \sum \frac{a_ib_ic_id_i}{a_ib_i(c_i+d_i)+c_id_i(a_i+b_i)}$$

Ref : Dan Sitaru from "Imad Zak Math Group" on facebook

Comment: it's different this OP problem